# Function error 'redefined'

Tags: c, function, arguments

Hello I am getting an error regarding my function - saying it's undefined and I can't understand what the compiler really wants. And no, I cannot use arrays, and I'm having trouble making global variables, so it's got to be done this way. The following error message is produced, when I run this:

> Error 4   error C2371: 'moveHandler' : redefinition; different basic types    c:\users\owner\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\project36\project36\source.c   120 1   Project36

function definition:

```
   void moveHandler( char source, char destination, char *pa, char *pb, char *pc, char *pd, char *pe, char *pf,
                     char *pg, char *ph, char *pi, char *pj, char *pk, char *pl, char *pm, char *pn, char *po ) {
                         char temp;

                         if ( source == 'D' && destination == 'A' ) {
                             temp = *pa;
                             *pa = *pd;
                             *pd = temp;
                         }
    return;
    }
```

function call:

```
moveHandler( sourcePiece, destination, &pa, &pb, &pc, &pd, &pe, &pf, &pg, &ph, &pi, &pj, &pk, &pl, &pm, &pn, &po);
```

Comment: Oh my... this is the longest argument list I've ever seen..

Comment: 15 board pieces + 2 other gen arguments, sorry.

Comment: Ever heard of arrays and/or structures?

Comment: I can't use them for this assignment and I'm having trouble getting global variables.

Comment: Are you calling this function before its definition? Perhaps *declaring* the function before your invocation may help.

Comment: You're calling moveHandler from another function, correct? NOT from the global context (you know you can't call functions from the global context)?

Comment: You should post a complete example that reproduces the errr: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Oh so that's what they were talking about before. Ok thank you now I know.

Comment: You had essentially this problem yesterday — [Argument error in function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42017188/).  You should learn from the answers and comments to your previous questions.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I'll review them before asking next time.

Answer (score 4):

You are calling an undeclared function in your C code. Make sure you declare C functions (with prototypes) before you attempt to call them.

And it makes sense to try doing a search on SO before asking a question. Searching for "redefinition; different basic types" would have immediately supplied you with a great variety of answers.

Answer (score 0):

If you call a function that the compiler can't find or doesn't know about, it assumes that it's just linked to from elsewhere (like, some other library that the linker will handle), and returns an `int`.

If you later define the function *after* the compiler has seen it be called (but not defined or declared in your code), the compiler will throw a redefinition error because it already decided that the function must exist externally and return an `int`.

To address this issue, declare all functions before defining any:

Bad:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
     printf("%d\n", add2(5, 6));
     return 0;
}
int add2(int a, int b)
{
     return a + b;
}
```

Good:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int add2(int a, int b);
int main()
{
     printf("%d\n", add2(5, 6));
}
int add2(int a, int b)
{
     return a + b;
}
```